# Ratio of primes in square diagonals | Problem 58 Project Euler

Tags: python-3.x, programming-challenge

I solved [problem 58](https://projecteuler.net/problem=58) in Project Euler and I am happy with my solution. However, are there any areas where I can improve my code here as I am learning how to write good python code.

Prompt:

> Starting with 1 and spiralling anticlockwise in the following way, a
> square spiral with side length 7 is formed.
>
> ```
> 37 36 35 34 33 32 31
> 38 17 16 15 14 13 30
> 39 18  5  4  3 12 29
> 40 19  6  1  2 11 28
> 41 20  7  8  9 10 27
> 42 21 22 23 24 25 26
> 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
> ```
>
> It is interesting to note that the odd squares lie along the bottom
> right diagonal, but what is more interesting is that 8 out of the 13
> numbers lying along both diagonals are prime; that is, a ratio of 8/13
> ≈ 62%.
>
> If one complete new layer is wrapped around the spiral above, a square
> spiral with side length 9 will be formed. If this process is
> continued, what is the side length of the square spiral for which the
> ratio of primes along both diagonals first falls below 10%?

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

from funcs import isPrime


# Corner values of a square of size s have values:
# s^2 - 3s + 3, s^2 - 2s + 2, s^2 - s + 1, s^2


def corner_values(n):
    """
    returns a tuple of all 4 corners of an nxn square

    >>> corner_values(3)
    (3, 5, 7, 9)
    """
    return (n ** 2 - 3 * n + 3, n ** 2 - 2 * n + 2, n ** 2 - n + 1, n ** 2)


def main():
    ratio, side_length = 1, 1
    primes, total = 0, 0
    while ratio >= 0.1:
        side_length += 2
        for n in corner_values(side_length):
            if isPrime(n):
                primes += 1
                total += 1
            else:
                total += 1
        ratio = primes / total
    return side_length - 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

Comment: What is funcs module?

Comment: @PavloSlavynskyy These are some local helper functions I have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Identifiers consistency

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends snake_case, not camelCase for functions and variables; `isPrime` breaks this. Moreover, PEP8 recommends consistency over other matters (except for readability). If it's your function - maybe you should rework it one way or another?

#### `main` is unclear name

Yes, it makes clear that it makes some "main work" in the file, but `find_prime_diagonals_size` (ok, bad example) or something like that could be more readable. How about `solve_euler58`?

#### DRY in if branches

If the last statement in both `if` and `else` branches is the same - it can be moved out and put after `if-else`:

```
        if isPrime(n):
            primes += 1
        total += 1
```

The same applies if you have first statement the same - it could be put before `if`.

#### `total` and `side_length` are loop variables and are defined by each other

`total` increases by 4 every `while` iteration, and `side_length` increases by 2. Consider using only 1 variable and (arguably) itertools.count, like

```
for side_length in itertools.count():
    ...
    if primes/(side_length*2-1)<0.1:
        return side_length
```

#### `corner_values` return a progression, so it can be replaced with range

```
range(n**2 - 3*n + 3, n**2 + 1, n - 1)
```

returns the same values as `corner_values`, even probably slightly faster, but I'm not sure if it's more readable. Probably not. Still, you should be aware of possibilities.

#### Divisions are slower than multiplications, floating point operations are slower than integers

It's not really important here; but I think you should know that. You're calculating `primes / total >= 0.1` every loop; multiply both sides by 10*total, and the expression will be `10 * primes >= total`, which calculates slightly faster. I don't think it's really needed here, it looks more readable in the first form, just FYI.

#### Complexity of `isPrime` is unknown

I think this is the bottleneck of the code. Does it use any sieve or is just a brute force division check?